# Take your pick usage

Tags: usage

**Take your pick - choose anyone you want**

Pick of **something** is usually used.

> We were reviewing the pick of new magazines.
>
> This is the pick of modern technologies.

But in a Cambridge dictionary sentence I found

> Take your pick of **any** dessert on the cart.

How is **any** used here. Is it grammatical?

Thanks in advance........

Answer (score 2):

**Any** is used here just as it would be used anywhere else.
It simply means that the listener can choose any of the deserts among many varieties that are present.